# Why does this JavaScript regex replace break this jQuery code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need this JavaScript to run when the page is loaded:

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/\} \}/g, '}}');
```

I also need this jQuery to run when the page is loaded (handles my sidebar):

```
$('[data-toggle=offcanvas]').click(function() {
    $('.row-offcanvas').toggleClass('active');
});
```

This works for the sidebar (placed just before `</body>`):

```
<script>$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[data-toggle=offcanvas]').click(function() {
    $('.row-offcanvas').toggleClass('active');
  });
});</script>
```

But if I add the regex line like this:

```
<script>$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[data-toggle=offcanvas]').click(function() {
    $('.row-offcanvas').toggleClass('active');
  });
  document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/\} \}/g, '}}');
});</script>
```

The regex works but the sidebar bit stops working. Is this because I'm mixing JavaScript and jQuery? How would I fix this?

Comment: This feels like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378).  **Why** do you need to run that regex? That looks like some escaped JSON or similar, that may be better handled in another way....

Comment: No, it's because you're replacing the content of your page with new content. The new content doesn't have event handlers. This is not a good way of doing whatever you are trying to do.

Comment: "Is this because I'm mixing Javascript and jQuery?" jQuery *is* javascript.

Comment: `document.body.innerHTML =  ...` replaces everything in the body, removing event handlers and pretty much everything else

Comment: Use event delegation and place `<script></script>` within `<head>` element

Comment: Ah I see. It's because the regex script is a hack to allow me to display `{{}}` on a page. The static site generator I'm using has a bug where (even in a code fence) it tries to process `{{}}` so I've had to resort to putting `{{} }` in my content so it's not processed. The regex converts the `{{} }` back to `{{}}`

Comment: @Garry, sounds like the site generator is expecting templating markup designated by double braces. You might be able to turn that off on the site generator.

Comment: Lessen the scope of your replacement to only areas of the dom that have said elements but don't have elements that have data.

Comment: @Jonathan M, doesn't look like that's an option. Although hacky, I know the double braces are always within a div with class `my-content`. Would only running the regex on that div stop the event handlers being removed?

Comment: how about if you use HTML escape codes for { and } there? &#123; and &#125;  Then you can get rid of that crazy regex entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are replacing the document body so your bindings are lost.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // change body
  document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/\} \}/g, '}}');
  // then bind to new body
  $('[data-toggle=offcanvas]').click(function() {
    $('.row-offcanvas').toggleClass('active');
  });

});
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a cleaner method based on your clarifying comment that the only double braces you want to replace are in the elements with class `my-content`:

```
$('.my-content').text().replace(/\} \}/g, '}}');
```